# Cannot find module '../build/Debug/iconv.node' on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, openshift, iconv, node-gyp

I'm trying to deploy a Node.js Wiki called [Jingo](https://github.com/claudioc/jingo) on OpenShift:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../build/Debug/iconv.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/550a72cf5973cac5c10000ca/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/icon
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
DEBUG: Program node jingo -c config.yaml exited with code 8
```

I've tried running node-gyp configure and node-gyp build at the command line but I do not have sufficient rights. I have also tried including node-gyp configure and node-gyp build in the package.json file as an install script but get the following error:

```
remote: > node-gyp configure; node-gyp build
remote:
remote: gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
remote: gyp info using node-gyp@0.12.2
remote: gyp info using node@0.10.25 | linux | x64
remote: gyp info spawn python
remote: gyp info spawn args [ '/opt/rh/v8314/root/usr/bin/gyp',
remote: gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
remote: gyp info spawn args   '-f',
remote: gyp info spawn args   'make',
remote: gyp info spawn args   '-I',
remote: gyp info spawn args   '/var/lib/openshift/550a72cf5973cac5c10000ca/app-root/runtime/repo/build/config.gypi',
remote: gyp info spawn args   '-I',
remote: gyp info spawn args   '/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/addon-rpm.gypi',
remote: gyp info spawn args   '-I',
remote: gyp info spawn args   '/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/share/node/common.gypi',
remote: gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
remote: gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
remote: gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/share/node',
remote: gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/var/lib/openshift/550a72cf5973cac5c10000ca/app-root/runtime/repo',
remote: gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
remote: gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
remote: gyp info spawn args   'build',
remote: gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
remote: gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /var/lib/openshift/550a72cf5973cac5c10000ca/app-root/runtime/repo) while trying to load binding.gyp
remote: gyp ERR! configure error
remote: gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
remote: gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:338:16)
remote: gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
remote: gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
remote: gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64
remote: gyp ERR! command "node" "/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure"
remote: gyp ERR! cwd /var/lib/openshift/550a72cf5973cac5c10000ca/app-root/runtime/repo
remote: gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.25
remote: gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
remote: gyp ERR! not ok
remote: gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
remote: gyp info using node-gyp@0.12.2
remote: gyp info using node@0.10.25 | linux | x64
remote: gyp info spawn make
remote: gypmake: Entering directory `/var/lib/openshift/550a72cf5973cac5c10000ca/app-root/runtime/repo/build'
remote: make: Leaving directory `/var/lib/openshift/550a72cf5973cac5c10000ca/app-root/runtime/repo/build'
remote:  info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
remote: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
remote: gyp ERR! build error
remote: gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
remote: gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
remote: gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
remote: gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
remote: gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64
remote: gyp ERR! command "node" "/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build"
remote: gyp ERR! cwd /var/lib/openshift/550a72cf5973cac5c10000ca/app-root/runtime/repo
remote: gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.25
remote: gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
remote: gyp ERR! not ok
remote:
remote: npm info jingo@1.2.6 Failed to exec install script
remote: npm ERR! jingo@1.2.6 install: `node-gyp configure; node-gyp build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the jingo@1.2.6 install script.
remote: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the jingo package,
remote: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
remote: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
remote: npm ERR!     node-gyp configure; node-gyp build
remote: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
remote: npm ERR!     npm owner ls jingo
remote: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64
remote: npm ERR! command "node" "/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-d"
remote: npm ERR! cwd /var/lib/openshift/550a72cf5973cac5c10000ca/app-root/runtime/repo
remote: npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
remote: npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /var/lib/openshift/550a72cf5973cac5c10000ca/app-root/runtime/repo/npm-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! not ok code 0
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control build' for /var/lib/openshift/550a72cf5973cac5c10000ca/nodejs
remote:
remote: For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.
To ssh://550a72cf5973cac5c10000ca@jingo-docusignau.rhcloud.com/~/git/jingo.git/
   f3b5d5e..db51a22  master -> master
```

Is there another way to install and configure node-gyp on OpenShift?

Comment: Hi! Did you resolved this issue? I am facing the same. It seems that iconv.node from ../node_modules/iconv/build folder is compiled for wrong architecture. But lscpu remotely on Openshift server shows me x64 arc, and my .node file is compiled for that x64 arc too. So annoying thing!

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to resolve the issue on Open Shift. I had to cut my losses and deploy on a Linux VM instead.

Comment: I have resolved it, but not clear understand which steps are helps. What I did: 1. Remove node_modules on server. 2. Redeployed project (to allow open shift generate node_modules folder). 3. In the iconv folder did node-gyp clear / config / build

Answer (score 2):

My resolution for this issue is rebuilding iconv inside module folder manually, or by adding script `install` in `package.json` like

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "install": "cd node_modules/iconv; node-gyp rebuild"
  }
```

This will force rebuilding `iconv.node` after every automatic deployment by `git push`

**UPD:** Another approach is to add script in `.openshift/action_hooks/build` at the end of file:

```
# rebuilding iconv
if [ -f "${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/node_modules/iconv"/package.json ]; then
      echo "  - Rebuilding iconv ... "
      echo
      (cd "${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/node_modules/iconv/"; node-gyp rebuild)
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Firuz, I believe I tried these suggestions already, but that was back in March. Perhaps something has changed in Open Shift since then, fingers crossed...